# Fix Polygons to be true Rectangles

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, polygon, extents

I got a featureclass polygon of 4 point polygons that delineate the coverage area of a georeferenced image; these polygons will later be map sheets. Anyway I discovered some of them are not true rectangles and I was wondering if there was a tool or script out there for either Arc or QGIS that could analyse a polygon and reshape it to be a perfect rectangle.

Comment: QGIS with Geoalgorithms-General tools-Get shapes extents? Basically any tool that gives the Envelope of geometries, but then you will probably get overlaps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used the one in Arc in a model that applied the function to each feature. It is good to know the solution in QGIS, when I work from home I do not have access to Arc only Q. Thanks again.
Edit: Sorry, I tried to vote your comment but accidentally clicked it twice, now it wont let me.

Comment: Not all image footprints will be "perfect rectangles", nor should they be if they were shot obliquely, or if any reprojection of the coordinates has been performed.  You may be on a mission to corrupt your data.

Comment: @user30184 correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the Envelope will always be oriented at right angles with the coordinate system, whereas the desired rectangles may be oriented at any angle. (But I also agree with Vince that this question may be misguided and the rectangles should be left alone)

Comment: @StephenLead, you are right with the envelopes. That's why I wrote that there may (or will) be overlaps. Envelopes are often used in image index files because they are good enough for that purpose. I will add an answer about how to creating true Minimum Bounding Rectangles with OpenJUMP. I agree that trying to create perfect rectangles may not make sense.

Comment: I am not concerned about corrupting anything; they are just polygons to act as view ports for future maps and I want them rectangles. I am only concerned about making sure they cover the area the original drawing did. 
I used Rectangle Shortest Distance in Arc, same tool different option, it creates a rectangle to cover the feature and will orient it to get the most feature coverage with the smallest rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a polygon into a perfect rectangle means the same than closing it inside a minimum bounding rectangle (MBR). There are two sorts of MBRs: an oriented rectangle which has its axes in the same direction as the coordinate system, or truly minimum rectangle which can be rotated. The oriented one is also called as Envelope.

Let's begin with two polygons.

[image]

The envelopes (created with OpenJUMP: Analysis - Geometry Functions - Envelope)

[image]

The Minimum Bounding Rectangles (created with OpenJUMP: Analysis - Geometry Functions - Minimum Bounding Rectangle):

[image]

However, I do not believe you should warp your image footprints to suit with these perfect rectangles. The footprints probably are as they are for reason.

Comment: great write-up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Attach this script:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

try:
    # input folder with shapefiles or rasters
    inputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    env.workspace = inputFolder
    # output folder for tiles shapefile
    outputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    # table name
    outputFile = "tiles.shp"
    theType=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
    if theType=='Shapefile':
        inRasters = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    elif theType=='Raster':
        inRasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
    arcpy.AddMessage(len(inRasters))
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outputFolder, outputFile, "POLYGON", "", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", "", "", "0", "0", "0")
    outputFile=outputFolder+ os.sep +outputFile
    arcpy.AddField_management(outputFile, "FILE_NAME", "TEXT", "", "", 250, "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    inRows = arcpy.InsertCursor(outputFile)
    arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "", 0, len(inRasters))
    for inRaster in inRasters:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(inRaster)
        ext=desc.extent
        thePoints=[ext.lowerLeft, ext.upperLeft,ext.upperRight,ext.lowerRight, ext.lowerLeft]
        pntarray = arcpy.Array(thePoints)
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(pntarray)
        row = inRows.newRow()
        row.Shape=polygon
        row.FILE_NAME=inputFolder+os.sep+inRaster
        inRows.insertRow(row)
        arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
        arcpy.AddMessage (inRaster + "...processed")

    del inRows
except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
            str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
    msgs = "GEOPROCESSOR ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
```

to tool:

[image]

Parameters are 1) input folder (the one that contains rasters or shapefiles) 2) output folder where tiles.shp will be created 3) string, value list = Shapefile; Raster

This is [help](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00150000000n000000.htm) on how define parameters